# ZeroBrane - Debug Corona SDK on linux

Tags: debugging, coronasdk, zerobrane

I'm starting to work with ZeroBrane for Corona SDK Starter license development under Linux using Wine. The problem is that i cannot make it work the debugger by adding breakpoints over different sections of the code.

The Corona Simulator path on the user.lua configuration is defined and opens the Simulator successfully, but the game is not paused by the breakpoints.

I also added the following line at the beggining of my main.lua file

```
require("mobdebug").start()
```

There is some way to make it work the debug session in Linux?

**Note**: Someone with the enough reputation, can create the zerobrane tag?

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints not working is usually caused by different paths reported by the Lua engine (in this case embedded in Corona SDK) and the IDE itself. You can see what path is being reported by your engine if you include something like this in your script: `print(debug.getinfo(1,"S").source)`

If you are running ZeroBrane Studio using Wine as well, you may want to try running it under Linux (while still running Corona SDK using Wine). ZBS will attempt to do partial matching between your project paths under Wine and Linux, which may work better in this particular case.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, feel free to send a message to [ZeroBrane Studio maillist](http://studio.zerobrane.com/community.html) and I can provide additional details on how to troubleshoot this further.